# Urdu and English in one Font in Crystal Reports

Tags: fonts, crystal-reports

I'm trying to use Urdu and English mix to make remarks in **crystal report** like:

.ھے(Ali)میرا نام علی

But When it appear in crystal report, it's become inconsistent like:

میرا نام علی ھے۔**(Ali)**

Please help in fixing this. Thanks

Comment: are urdu and english fields saperate are both in format in same database field

Comment: Yes, I have saved it in nvarchar in database, when I retrieve it from database into string, it is in correct format, but when it appear in crystal report become in consistent due to Font. Actually font make it in consist. There is no any font that support both urdu and english... how can I fix it? Help me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, the simple solution that I found is to use different text boxes for English as well as for Urdu and arrange them accordingly.